# Spring Boot reading yml null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, autowired

I was trying to get the value from yml file

here is my application.yml-

```
inbox:  
  inboxlist:
    -INBOX
    -TEST
```

and here's where the data store in- InboxConfig.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "inbox")
public class InboxConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InboxConfig.class);

    private List<String> inboxlist;
```

(note I use lombok so there's no getter)

And here's where I called it

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SFEmailServiceHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFEmailServiceHandler.class);
    
    ArrayList<String> mailTo = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Autowired
    protected InboxConfig inboxConfig;
    List<String> Inboxlist = inboxConfig.getInboxlist();
```

but I get `Cannot invoke "*myorg*.InboxConfig.getInboxlist()" because "this.inboxConfig" is null`

Did I miss something? I'm new to Spring boot, and I can't really figure out how the Autowired work.

Answer (score 1):

Use @PostConstruct

This method will be invoked after autowiring(injection).

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SFEmailServiceHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFEmailServiceHandler.class);

    ArrayList<String> mailTo;

    @Autowired
    protected InboxConfig inboxConfig;
    List<String> Inboxlist;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        mailTo = new ArrayList<String>();
        Inboxlist = inboxConfig.getInboxlist();
    }
}
```

Comment: That probably work? now I get `Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "this.Inboxlist" is null` .  I'm doubt there is something I still forgot. seems like it still not injection the data in.

Answer (score 0):

You must also register the class as "springbean" before you can obtain the list values.

example)

```yaml
inbox:
  inboxlist:
    - INBOX  # Add space... 
    - TEST
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(InboxConfig.class)
public class SFEmailServiceHandler {

    @Autowired
    protected InboxConfig inboxConfig;
    List<String> inboxlist;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        this.inboxlist = inboxConfig.getInboxlist();
        log.info("inboxlist : {} ", inboxlist);
    }
}
```